# Direct formula to calculate the sum.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

We often encounter this in permutations and combinations.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} {^{n}}P_{k}= ?$$

Is there any direct formula to calculate this sum because it's tedious to do this for large values of $n$? If there is, can you please share it with its proof?

Comment: From Wolfram|Alpha, the sum has no 'nice' formula to it. It can be written as an incomplete gamma function, which is pretty much a paraphrase of the sigma notation.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En%5Cfrac%7Bn!%7D%7B(n-k)!%7D

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926440/series-expansion-of-incomplete-gamma-function-ratio for a nice approximation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that we have $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} {^{n}P_{k}} = n! \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(n-k)!}=n! [\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\frac{1}{(n-2)!}+…\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{0!}]\tag{1}$$ This basically boils down to calculating the sum of reciprocals of the first $n$ factorials (including zero). Now, we have a representation of the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Upper_incomplete_Gamma_function) as: $$\Gamma(s,x) = (s-1)!e^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^{s-1}\frac{x^k}{k!}\, \,, s\in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$$

We can then easily see that $(1)$ can be represented as $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} {^{n}P_{k}} = e\Gamma(n+1,1)-1$$

---

However, as Karn correctly pointed out, the main aim of a closed form for the sum of the permutations is defeated by this Gamma representation which is equivalent to *“a paraphrase of the sigma notation”*.