# Show that $\sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(it)^j}{(k+j)!}$ is bounded for any fixed $k>2$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

We already know that $e^{it}$ is bounded by 1 uniformly for all real $t$. And the taylor series of it is actually $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(it)^j}{(k+j)!}-1$ with $k=0$. Here I figured with $k>2$, the norm is supposed to be smaller. But it is much trickier than I thought. I can't use triangle inequality here since I need a uniform bound over all t. And I can't just factor out something to extract a $e^{it}$ factor. After much work, I haven't been able to show it is uniformly bounded for all real t. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think the real and imaginary parts are alternating, so you just have to find the largest of each.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the fastest way to estimate the function is to observe
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{j=1} \frac{(it)^j}{(j+k)!}= e^{it}\frac{(it)^{-k}}{\Gamma(k)}\gamma(k, it) -1=(it)e^{it}\frac{(it)^{-k-1}}{\Gamma(k+1)}\gamma(k+1, it)
\end{align}
where $\Gamma(k)$ is the gamma function and $\gamma(s, z)$ is the [lower incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Lower_incomplete_Gamma_function) defined by
\begin{align}
\gamma(s, z) = z^s \sum^\infty_{j=0} \frac{(-1)^j z^j}{j! (j+s)}.
\end{align}

Hence it suffices to consider the normalized lower incomplete gamma function
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{(it)^{-k}\gamma(k, it)}{\Gamma(k)} \right|
\end{align}
for $t$ large, say $|t|\gg k$, and show it's bounded. By [the series expansion of the normalised incomplete gamma function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926440/series-expansion-of-incomplete-gamma-function-ratio), we see that

\begin{align}
(it)^{-k}\frac{\gamma(k, it)}{\Gamma(k)} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(k)} \int^\infty_0 e^{-(k-1)s}e^{-it e^{-s}}\ ds.
\end{align}
Next, apply [the method of non-stationary phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Corput_lemma_(harmonic_analysis)), we see that
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{1}{\Gamma(k)} \int^\infty_0 e^{-(k-1)s}e^{-it e^{-s}}\ ds \right|\leq \frac{C}{\Gamma(k)|t|}
\end{align}
for some constant $C=C(k)$, can depend on $k$. Hence it follows
\begin{align}
\left|\sum^\infty_{j=1} \frac{(it)^j}{(j+k)!} \right|\leq \frac{C}{ \Gamma(k+1)}.
\end{align}

**Note:** In fact, one could probably check that $C(k) = 1$. I believe this is as sharp as it will ever get.

**Additional:** Observe
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 e^{-(k-1)s}e^{-it e^{-s}}\ ds =&\ \frac{1}{it}\int^\infty_0 e^{-(k-2)s}\frac{d}{ds}e^{-it e^{-s}}\ ds\\
=&\ \frac{1}{it}\left[e^{-(k-2)s-ite^{-s}}\bigg|^\infty_{s=0}+(k-2)\int^\infty_0 e^{-(k-2)s-ite^{-s}}\ ds \right]\\
=&\ \frac{e^{-it}}{it}+ \frac{k-2}{it}\int^\infty_0e^{-(k-2)s-ite^{-s}}\ ds.
\end{align} 
Next, note that
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{e^{-it}}{it}+ \frac{k-2}{it}\int^\infty_0e^{-(k-2)s-ite^{-s}}\ ds\right| \leq \frac{1}{|t|}+\frac{k-2}{|t|}\int^\infty_0 e^{-(k-2)s}\ ds = \frac{2}{|t|}.
\end{align}
Hence, we in fact have
\begin{align}
\left|\int^\infty_0 e^{-(k-1)s}e^{-it e^{-s}}\ ds\right| \leq \frac{2}{\Gamma(k)|t|}
\end{align}
where $t$ is big.

Comment: I'm stuck here: $\sum^\infty_{j=1} \frac{(it)^j}{(j+k)!}= e^{it}\frac{(it)^{-k}}{\Gamma(k)}\gamma(k, it) -1$. Cancellation does not show the equality. Did you skip some steps here?

Comment: For example, what am I supposed to do with $e^{it}$ here? Should I expand it? And how to recover the $(j+k)!$ term?

Comment: @DanielLi The first step I apply the definition (power series expansion) as indicated in the wiki page.

Comment: For your own sake, first assume you have the identity.