# Asymptotic behavior of Gamma cdf, gamma function, and incomplete gamma function

Tags: asymptotics, gamma-function, gamma-distribution

For the sake of this post, we only look at real-valued gamma functions.

We know that $\lim_{b \to \infty}\gamma(a,b)=\Gamma(a)$, so we have

$$\lim_{b \to \infty} \frac{\gamma(a,b)}{\Gamma(a)}=1.$$

[How to prove asymptotic limit of an incomplete Gamma function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200140/how-to-prove-asymptotic-limit-of-an-incomplete-gamma-function) shows that

$$\lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{\gamma(a,b)}{\Gamma(a)}=0.$$

I also remembered one result, although I cannot recall the reference:

$$\lim_{a \to  \infty} \frac{\Gamma(a,a)}{\Gamma(a)}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Therefore, we also have $$\lim_{a \to  \infty} \frac{\gamma(a,a)}{\Gamma(a)}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

I am curious about the following limit, can we conjecture that for general $a>0,b>0$:
$$\lim_{k \to  \infty} \frac{\gamma(ak,bk)}{\Gamma(ak)}=\frac{1}{2}?$$

Thank you.

Comment: [$(8.12.3)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.12.E3) shows that the limit is $1/2$ if $a=b$, is $1$ if $b>a$, and is $0$ if $b<a$. You could have done some numerical tests to see if your conjecture is feasible before posting a question here.

Comment: @Gary I am not aware of this website. Thank you. However, what is the definition of $S(a,\eta)$? I don't seem to find a definition of it from the web page, only its asymptotic equivalence.

Comment: It is only given as an asymptotic expansion. You can solve  (8.12.3) for it and you have a definition. You can find more information, e.g. references, in the infoboxes on the page by clicking on the "i" icons on the right side.